# Is there a way to Automate Kustos Queries (KQL) files to run?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quarkus, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to find any solutions or reference where I can run the bunch of KQL files which has the unit test via automated script? What is the best way to automate the KQL unit test? Currently am running it manually these unit test cases but want to convert it to automation. I can create a microservice in spring boot or quarkus but how to read this in the java and automate it? Not just with java any other way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Java library provided by Microsoft for this called azure-kusto-java.

It is available on Maven Central as two separate packages.

One for queries:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.kusto/kusto-data

And one for ingestion:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.kusto/kusto-ingest

[Here's the GitHub repo.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java)

Additionally, I just wrapped up work on a Quarkus extension to simplify the process, however I need to get it approved for release into the wild.

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing to the right direction. I already have the unit test queries written in a file and I want to run it through automation and now running that manually. Is there a way I can create a service and feed these file to read the queries and run it?

Comment: Sure. With the existing libraries you would just need to create a client class and then pass the files to the client. The kusto library interprets your query from a string, so all you would need to do is read your files to a string. Be sure to use the ClientRequestProperties class from the library if you take user input at any point in time during your query generation, so as to prevent any chance of an injection style attack.

Comment: Amazing, appreciate your valuable suggestion and I checked and accepted your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @sam I will keep you updated if my extension is made public.

Answer (score 1):

there are client libraries provided in multiple programming languages you can use as part of your automation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/client-libraries

you can also use the Kusto.Cli tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-cli